# Problems trying to find the root category based on category id

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to figure out the root level category_id of a category based on it's parent_id.

In the function below **$this->cat_arr** is an array of all categories and their parent_id's.

If a parent_id is set to 0 it is assumed to be a root node. I wish to loop through the array until I find the parent_id of passed **$cat_id**.

```
function getRoot($cat_id) {
    foreach ($this->cat_arr as $row) {
        if ($row->cat_id == $cat_id && $row->parent_id == 0) {
            return $row->cat_id;
            break;
        } else {
            $this->getRoot($row->parent_id);
        }
    }
}
```

In my application I only call this function when I know **$cat_id** is not at the root level (because the parent_id is greater than 0), but when I try to run this it gets stuck in an infinite loop.

Is my logic flawed, or am I missing something simple?

Comment: Just a quick thought, but your expression: == 0 might need a set of single quotes '0' cause it might be reading that as FALSE as opposed to zero (I could be totally wrong, but just thought I would make a suggestion)

Comment: @OldWest: you're totally wrong ;-)

Comment: You are infinite looping because each time you recurse, you are starting the foreach at the beginning again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getRoot($cat_id) {
    foreach ($this->cat_arr as $row) {
        if ($row->cat_id == $cat_id && $row->parent_id == 0) {
            return $row->cat_id;
        }
    }
    return $this->getRoot($row->parent_id);
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion is getting me closer. I am now finding that all categories that have a parent_id of 0 are returning the same root. I am trying to make sense of why, and perhaps once I understand the reason the solution will present itself.

Comment: I am going to go ahead and mark your suggestion as the answer as it did address the main issue of my question, breaking the infinite loop. I still see a logic issue with the function overall so for those who may be reading this later, this is NOT a correct way to determine a root category based on the parameters I have provided in this question.